# Can HSG + TIM + HSG sandwich ever be better than one layer of HSG?

Tags: thermal, heatsink, interface

Here is a photo of a big diode and it's TIM (thermal interface material.)  The foil appears to be aluminum, very thin and reflective, with white, crusty HSG (heatsink grease / paste / compound) on both sides:

[image: Large diode and metallic film Thermal Interface Material]

Why would this diode be installed with an *aluminum TIM*?

Even if it were a rare-Earth alloy, the fact that it comprises a three-layer-sandwich would surely be worse (thermally) than one layer of quality thermal grease, no?  The heatsink it was mounted to had a smoother surface finish than most, so I'm wondering why a TIM was used.  Is this just for assembly convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the datasheets I've seen for pre-coated pads for SSR mounting mention ease of use.  If they have phase-change interface material than they can rival or even exceed the performance of regular old boron nitride grease while being quicker and cleaner to apply (try getting a nice even layer with the "deodorant stick" phase change material - what a nightmare!).  And I'm not sure if it's applicable to your diode but a lot of the SSRs try to make the thermal solution as effortless as possible: "use this relay with this thermal pad, at this torque, on this heatsink, and you will be good up to 50 A at 55 C ambient".